# UITableView and changing datasource while the table is being rendered

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray

I have a view controller with an `UITableView`. The data source of the table view is an `NSArray` that is being loaded asynchronously from the net.

The first time the data is being loaded, everything is fine, but since that data is also refreshing itself from time to time, I noticed that I have a racing condition when the UITableView is still rendering the cells and thus calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` while the NSArray is being set to a different value by the asynchronous operation that has just finished fetching the new data.

I believe that the `numberOfRowsInSection` has returned the length of the old NSArray and the UITableView is rendering the cells based on that value. But in the meanwhile my NSArray has been reloaded and it's got fewer objects, so the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is actually trying to index a value that is outside the bounds of the array.

Is there a way to interrupt the rendering of the cells or, better yet, to know when the UITableView has finished rendering its cells, so that I can update the datasource?

Is there any other approach to this kind of problem?

**UPDATE: I've added sample code**

The delegates:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return [_rootCategories count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RootCell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ALTRootCategoryCell alloc] init];
    }
    ALTRootCategoryCell *rcc = (ALTRootCategoryCell *)cell;
    ALTRootCategory *rc = [_rootCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%d punti)", rc.title, [rc.valueMax intValue]];
    rcc.title.text = s;
    return cell;
}
```

And the code that does the async fetch is pretty much like this:

```
[[ALTWebService sharedInstance] rootCategory:^(NSArray *result) {
    _rootCategories = [[ALTWebService sharedInstance] fetchRootCategories];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_mainTable reloadData];
        [[ALTNotificationManager sharedInstance] manageSavedNotification];
    });
} failure:^(NSString *error) {
    [ALTAlert dismiss];
    [ALTAlert error:error];
    hasErrors = YES;
}];
```

Comment: @mehulpatel yes, but if I change the NSArray and let's say that the old had 5 items and the new one has only 3, I will get the array out of bounds exception if it's still rendering the 5 cells from the previous array.

Answer (score 0):

You should call [reloadData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData) method to update table after changing DataSource:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: I already do that, but the array gets reassigned before `reloadData` is being called.

Comment: @ValerioSantinelli probably you have some problems with virtualisation. Did you override -prepareForReuse in ALTRootCategoryCell?

Comment: No, I didn't override `prepareForReuse`. The only special thing about that cell is that it contains an `UICollectionView` but this problem is happening even with cells with just an `UILabel`.